# Python 3 + SQLite check

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, mysql-python

**Hello**
I have a question about SQLite functions, maybe.

So, question:

**How to check if *name* I set in Python is in certain column?**

*Example:*

```
name = 'John'

Table name = my_table

Column name = users
```

Code details:

```
C = conn.cursor()
```

Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parameter in the query as required. See the attached example for better understanding.

**Sample SQLite code for searching value in tables**

```
import sqlite3 as sqlite
import sys

conn = sqlite.connect("test.db")

def insert_single_row(name, age):    
    try:
        age = str(age)
        with conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USER_TABLE(NAME TEXT, AGE INTEGER);")
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO USER_TABLE(NAME, AGE) VALUES ('"+name+"',"+age+")")
            return cursor.lastrowid
    except:
        raise ValueError('Error occurred in insert_single_row(name, age)')

def get_parameterized_row(name):
    try:
        with conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM USER_TABLE WHERE NAME = :NAME",
                           {"NAME":name})
            conn.commit()
            return cursor.fetchall()
    except:
        raise ValueError('Error occurred in get_parameterized_row(name)')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        return_id = insert_single_row("Shovon", 24)
        return_id = insert_single_row("Shovon", 23)
        return_id = insert_single_row("Sho", 24)
        all_row = get_parameterized_row("Shovon")
        for row in all_row:
            print(row)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

**Output:**

```
('Shovon', 24)
('Shovon', 23)
```

Here I have created a table called `USER_TABLE` with two attributes: `NAME` and `AGE`. Then I inserted several values in the table and searched for a specific `NAME`. Hope it gives a way to start using SQLite in the project.

Comment: Thank you! I'll see what can I do. Is there another (shorter) way to check if *VARIABLE* in certain table?

Comment: Try to implement `get_parameterized_row(name)` method mentioned above in your situation. It is good practice to try catch in database operations which might make the code a bit longer.